# Do I need to recreate database relationships in java spring if they already exist in the database?

Tags: spring, spring-data

When creating an entity in java spring, do I still need to specify the relationships that are already created inside the database?

For example, userId is a primary key in the 'user' table and a foreign key in the 'order' table, and they have a one-to-many relationship (a user can have multiple orders) and this relationship is created inside the database, do I need to recreate that relationship using the appropriate annotations in java spring?

Thank you.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Take a tour and get your first badge-https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Check this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-relationships for your question about relationships in java spring, by using spring-data

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary, although it is recommendable because this way you can get your joins done without have to write a sql sentence using directly your jdbc driver.

The way to do this and most preferrable way if you are using spring is with springdata (with an orm that by default is hibernate). So you have to tag your entities with the @Entity annotation and mark each relation between entities with @ManyToOne or @OneToMany or if it is one to one adding it as an attribute of the other entity.

I suggest you to read this
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Answer (score 0):

The great advantage of using @OneToMany annotations etc..
is that the results of the links are created directly in the entity participating in the relationship.
As in the example here : https://hellokoding.com/jpa-one-to-many-relationship-mapping-example-with-spring-boot-maven-and-mysql/

```
@Entity(name = "BookCategory")
@Table(name = "book_category")
public class BookCategory {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "category_name")
private String name;

@OneToMany(
    mappedBy = "bookCategory",
    cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,
    fetch = FetchType.LAZY
)
private Set<Book> books;  
....
```

**books** contains all the elements that satisfy the relationship.
If you use a search with Sql type Select * from mytable left join etc ... the could look different from your Entity with the result that you have to create a new object with which to manage query data.
I believe that all this is longer and more difficult to manage and maintain.